Find a number $\delta \gt 0$ such that if $\vert x-a \vert \lt \delta$, then $\vert f(x)-L \vert$ will be less than the given number $\epsilon$.
The problem:
Find a number $\delta \gt 0$ such that if $\vert x-a \vert \lt \delta$, then $\vert f(x)-L \vert$ will be less than the given number $\epsilon$.
$f(x)=3x+1, a=2, L=7, \epsilon = 0.03$
The solution:
$\delta = 0.01$
What I have tried:
$\vert f(x)-L \vert \lt \epsilon$
$-\epsilon \lt f(x)-L \lt \epsilon$
$L- \epsilon \lt f(x) \lt L + \epsilon$
$L- \epsilon \lt 3x+1 \lt L + \epsilon$
$L-1- \epsilon \lt 3x \lt L-1+ \epsilon$
$\frac{L-1- \epsilon}{3} \lt x \lt \frac{L-1+ \epsilon}{3}$
$\frac{7-1-0.03}{3} \lt x \lt \frac{7-1+0.03}{3}$
$1.99 \lt x \lt 2.01$
$x \in (1.99, 2.01)$
$\vert x-a \vert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \vert 1.99-2 \vert \lt \delta \iff \vert -0.01 \vert \lt \delta \iff 0.01 \lt \delta$
$\vert x-a \vert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \vert 2.01-2 \vert \lt \delta \iff \vert 0.01 \vert \lt \delta \iff 0.01 \lt \delta$
My question:
Why is the solution $\delta = 0.01$ and not $\delta \gt 0.01$? I get $\delta \gt 0.01$, not $\delta \ge 0.01$. How can $\delta$ possibly equal to $0.01$?

$|f(x)-7|=3|x-2|.$ Therefore $|f(x)-7|<\varepsilon $ iff $|x-2|<{\varepsilon \over 3}.$

"Find a number ..."  You are correct: There is more than one answer possible.  If it asked "Find the number ..." it would not be possible.

Yeah, but wouldn't it be a number greater than $0.01$ since $\delta \gt 0.01$?

You've made a slight mistake in the order that you do things, which might be what's causing you confusion.
It is true that if $x \in (1.99, 2.01)$ then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, and this is equivalent to $|x - 2| < 0.01$.
However, this means that if we want to find a $\delta$ such that $|x - 2| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, we need to choose it so that:
$$|x - 2| < \delta \implies |x - 2| < 0.01$$
i.e. we need to give ourselves an interval that is smaller  (or at least not bigger) than $\pm 0.01$. This is because we need the implication to hold in the given direction. Because of this, we need $\delta \leq 0.01$, because then any $x \in (2 - \delta, 2 + \delta)$ is also guaranteed to be in $(1.99, 2.01)$.
By comparison, if we chose a bigger $\delta$, say $\delta = 0.1$, then we get an interval $(1.9, 2.1)$. And we can pick an $x$ in this interval, such as $x = 1.95$, and see that $|f(x) - L| = |(3 \times 1.95 + 1) - 7| = 0.15 > \epsilon$, so the implication fails.
